# Report - Periodic

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

How to design a periodic report in SSRS. I need just logical steps. report looks like below.

```
                Period 1 - 1/1/2014 - 1/15/2014         



Origin    Destination  # of loads   Average Billable  Average Expenses     Average Profit       
a         b              2          100               50                   50
c         d              3          300               50                   250
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- First create a report with two parameter startdate and enddate and then create a Dataset with Query like (change logic according to requirement)... Map the parameter value at DataSet Property

```
SELECT Origin,Destination,loads,Average(Billable),Average(Expenses),Average(Profit)
      FROM Table1 
      WHERE DateCol BETWEEN   @startdate and @enddate
      Group by Origin,Destination,loads
```